# Need to Integrate In-app Purchase for Video Calling with Patients in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, digital

I am developing a TeleMedicine App, in which patient can book an appointment with doctor for

-Face-to-Face Meeting

-Through Video Calling Session

by adding Stripe as a payment gateway.

Do I need to add In-app Purchase in my app for having video calling session with patients for both android and ios

Comment: I would suggest you ask Apple for a ruling on the appropriate payment method; as they may consider a video consultation to actually be a medical service that is delivered outside the app.

Comment: May I kindly ask you how your situation was handled? What method did you implement and did Apple deny the app if you had not used IAP?

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an application which doesn't deliver physical content to the customer than you will need to compulsory use in-app purchase for the payment.

According to apple clause section no 11.2

> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be
>   rejected

You can use the Subscription method of in-app purchase for making payment from the customers in the application.

Comment: I understand but the video consultation feature will be provided within my app.
Now user has the option to got to clinic for consultation or  get consultation through video call by making payment through stripe.

Answer (score 1):

No need In-app Purchase for this app
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118698

3.1.5(a) Goods and Services Outside of the App
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#goods-and-services

https://technode.com/2019/07/19/apple-gives-up-tax-on-medical-apps-after-outcry-from-developers/